# Invariant factors of a cyclic $K[X]$-module and of its dual

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $Q\in\mathbb{K}[X]$ be a non zero polynomial of degree $m$. ($\mathbb{K}$ is a field.)

We consider the $\mathbb{K}[X]$-module $M_Q = \mathbb{K}[X] / (Q) $.

1. What are the invariant factors of $M_Q$ and ${M_Q}^*$ (the dual space of $M_Q $)?
2. Does there exist an example of a $\mathbb{K}[X]$-module which is of finite dimension over $\mathbb{K}$ such that $M$ and $M^*$ are not isomorphic?
3. Does there exist a square matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb{K}) $ which is not similar to its transpose $ A^T $ ?

---

So most examples of invariants factors I see are with modules over $ \mathbb{Z} $ or $ \mathbb{Z}[i] $ but here we are looking at a module over a polynomial ring.

I have been trying to find the presentation matrix of $M_Q$ but I'm not sure how to proceed...

As $ M_Q = \left< \overline{1}, \overline{X}, \overline{X^2}, ... , \overline{X^{m-1}} \right> $ first we need to solve $ \ker(\varphi) $ with

$ \varphi :  \mathbb{K}[X]^m \rightarrow M_Q $

$  (r_i)_{i=0,1,\dots,m-1} \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} r_i \overline{X^i} $

which here is just a surjective homomorphism as $ M_Q$ may not be a free module.

Would $ r_i = QX^k $ with $ 0 \leq k \leq m-1 $ fit for the kernel?

Thanks in advance for any insights given on the matter.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I don't follow you: is $M_Q*$ the dual as a $K[X]$-module or as a $K$-vector space?

Comment: @Bernard Yes it's the dual as a K[X]-module, it's external operation is defined as P.f (m) = f(P.m)  with P a polynomial, f a linear form and m an element of M. Also K here is a field so that K[X] is indeed a PID.

Comment: It seems that $M_Q^*$ is the dual of $M_Q$ as $K$-vectorspace endowed with a structure of $K[X]$-module as the OP said: $(Xf)(m)=f(Xm)$ for $f\in M_Q^*$.

Answer (score 0):

For the question 2.

$M_Q^*= Hom_K(M_Q,K)$ with its natural $K[X]$-module structure $(X\cdot f)(a)=f(X  a)$.

Factorize $Q=\prod_j P_j^{e_j}$, let $R_i=P_i^{e_i-1}\prod_{j\ne i} P_j^{e_j}\in K[X]/(Q)$ and take $f\in M_Q^*$ such that $f(R_i)\ne 0$ for each $i$.

Then $$\ker(K[X]\to K[X]\cdot f )= (Q)$$
Therefore $\dim_K(K[X]\cdot f)= \dim_K(M_Q)=\dim_K(M_Q^*)$ so that as $K[X]$-modules $$ M_Q^*=K[X]\cdot f \cong K[X]/(Q)=M_Q$$
Such a $f$ exists because we can take $f_i\in Hom_K(K[X]/(P_i^{e_i}),K), f_i(R_i)=1$ and $f=\sum_i f_i$.

Comment: Otherwise do you agree with the argument of taking $f\in M_Q^*$ non-zero on each $R_i$? It don't see much alternatives.